# How to get your own questions with specific tag?

Tags: support, questions, search

I remember asking one specific question that was answered correctly. But now I can not find it.

So, how do I list all my questions with specific tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for `user:me is:question [tag]`.

Help: https://stackoverflow.com/search

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Rocket said, there is another way : open the profile, and select the tags tab. Clicking on the left number of a tag list all answers with that tag, and clicking on the tag lists all questions with the tag.